# How to get a fullscreen with tabs in Firefox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, fullscreen

I want to have a fullscreen with the tabs bar in Firefox running on top of Ubuntu 14.10, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you try the F11 shortcut??

Comment: :) It does not make the tab bar permanently shown!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for Firefox 69:

- Go to configuration editor by opening `about:config`
- Click on *I accept the risk!* when asked.
- Change value of `browser.fullscreen.autohide` setting from `true` to `false`.